# Flutter stuck at observatory listening

Tags: flutter

I have an error when running the application on my vivo Mobile where it is always stuck and there are no more processes only white screen show.

Comment: have the same! Did you solve it?

Comment: no solution yet .

Answer (score 0):

Debugger shows:
Observatory Listening on ********************* , on VIVO Devices

I don't have a proper solution, but this might help you to run the app on your phone (FunTouch OS where the problem occurred)

```
flutter run --release
```

Apparently, the release run is executed properly, and this will give you a hard time debugging. But at least it works.